# Filter Observable<T[]> to get a specific Observable<T> in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

For learning Angular, I mocked a web service that does two things:

1. returns an Observable of an array (`Observable<T[]>`)
2. returns an item identified by ID as an Observable (`Observable<T>`)

This is how I acheved this:

```
export class Event {
    constructor(public id: number, public title: string) {}
}

const EVENTS = [
    new Event(1, 'Tooth extraction'),
    new Event(2, 'English lesson'),
    new Event(3, 'Driving lesson'),
    new Event(4, 'Mortgage meeting'),
];

let eventsObservable: Observable<Event[]> = Observable.of(EVENTS);

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {

    getEvents() {
        return eventsObservable;
    }

    getEvent(id: number|string) {
        return eventsObservable.concatMap((x) => {
           return x;
        }).filter((event: Event) => {
            return id === event.id;
        });
    };
}
```

I've only started with Observable and Angular, however, I do not think that my implementation of `getEvent(id: number|string)` is optimal due to the fact that what I'm doing is:

1. Tak each item in `Observable<T[]>`,
2. Emit **each of those** as `Observable<T>`,
3. Only then filter the emitted items to find one that I'm looking for,
4. Return this item as an Observable.

Is there a better, more optimal way to just return a unique item from `Observable<T[]>`?

Comment: why not just `return Observable.from(EVENTS.filter(e => e.id === id)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better, more optimal way to just return a unique item from Observable?

Use `map` which takes an observable and returns a new observable based on the logic passed into the function.

```
getEvent(id: number | string) : Observable<Event> {
    return eventsObservable.map((x:Event[]):Event => {
        return x.find(y => y.id === id);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to use RxJS at all for this but I guess you're using Observables because there's some other functionality attached to them later.

I think the only thing to make this more readable is not using `Observable.of()` that just reemits the value and use `Observable.from()` that iterates the array and emits each value as a separate item.

```
let eventsObservable: Observable<Event> = Observable.from(EVENTS);

...

getEvent(id: number|string) {
    return eventsObservable
      .filter((event: Event) => {
          return id === event.id;
      });
}
```

Eventually if you need to keep events as an array in `Observable<Event[]>` you can flatten it with `concatAll` which makes it easier to understand.

```
getEvent(id: number|string) {
    return eventsObservable
      .concatAll()
      .filter((event: Event) => {
          return id === event.id;
      });
};
```

The `concatAll()` operator turns `Observable<Event[]>` into `Observable<Event>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you literally want can be done this way :

```js
getEvent(id: number|string) {
        return eventsObservable.flatMap((x) => Observable.from(x)).filter((event: Event) => {
            return id === event.id;
        });
    };
```

but note that it does not make much sense while you can just use `.map(array=>array.find(...))` as @Igor suggests and avoid one unnecessary iteration over the array.